# Download album art from internet in an android application

Tags: java, android, albumart

I know the artist and trackname for a song, but I am unsure of what service or how to download album art for the track.

I believe iTunes and Amazon both offer services but I am unsure of how to integrate these services, any links or suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To use Amazon you'll need to sign up as a developer for their public web services.

[Product Advertising API](https://affiliate-program.amazon.com/gp/advertising/api/detail/main.html)

This is mainly just to get the access key that you'll need for making your calls to their web service API.

You'll need to do a product search using the artist and album name, this will return an ASIN number. Once you have that number you can build the URL to the actual album art, ie:

```
http://images.amazon.com/images/P/*ASIN goes here*.01._SCLZZZZZZZ_.jpg
```

Comment: Thank you! Is there a reason for the .01._SCLZZZZZZZ_.jpg part though? Im finding so far that http://images.amazon.com/images/P/#ASIN#.jpg (where #ASIN# is the actual asin) works.

Comment: To be honest there may no longer be a need for that section of the URL. I was referencing code that I wrote awhile ago when I responded, so the URL structure may have changed since I wrote that code.

Comment: @AnkitSrivastava Looks like the response is always XML. [Here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/latest/DG/AuthJavaSampleSig2.html) is a code sample for making a request using REST.