# Why does content resolver return null values for album-art URI?

Tags: android

I queried for `ALBUM_ART` and `ALBUM` and dumped the cursor

```
final Cursor mCursor = getContentResolver().query(
                MediaStore.Audio.Albums.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                new String[]{MediaStore.Audio.Albums.ALBUM_ART},
                MediaStore.Audio.Albums._ID + "=?",
                albumID,
                null
        );

if (mCursor.moveToFirst()) {

DatabaseUtils.dumpCursor(mCursor);
mCursor.close();

} else {

mCursor.close();

}
```

Here is the cursor dump output

```
System.out: 0 {
System.out:    album_art=/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.android.providers.media/albumthumbs/1445591197242
System.out:    album=Samsung
System.out: }
System.out: 1 {
System.out:    album_art=null
System.out:    album=The Piano Starts Here
System.out: }
System.out: 2 {
System.out:    album_art=/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.android.providers.media/albumthumbs/1446000978698
System.out:    album=Maiden Voyage
System.out: }
System.out: 3 {
System.out:    album_art=/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.android.providers.media/albumthumbs/1446001599761
```

One can see that album **The Piano Starts Here** has `null` `ALBUM_ART`

```
System.out:    album_art=null
System.out:    album=The Piano Starts Here
```

However, having downloading a random music player from the Play store, I can see that somehow, this music player (among others but not all) is able find the album art somewhere on my phone. This art is not coming from some random image file in my music folder.

Where is it coming from? I didn't download this music onto my phone. I transferred it from my computer.

[image]

Comment: Most commercial music apps in google play store saves the downloaded album arts into it is data folder in case you remove thier application, you will lose them.

Comment: No, I didn't download this music onto my phone. I transferred it from my computer.

Comment: You are still probably using a modern music app to play it right? For example PowerAmp does that behaviour if you enable it from it is settings.

Comment: True, Power Amp does have that setting, but I am still not convinced the album art is being downloaded.

Comment: I am not using Power Amp btw

Comment: Okay you are right! That was the explanation. How does Power Amp and other music apps do that?!

Comment: If you want make a detailed response, I will check mark your answer.

Comment: So I need to use an [API](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2730948/download-album-art-from-internet-in-an-android-application). Thanks a lot! I will check mark your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most commercial music apps in google play store saves the downloaded album arts into it is data folder. You can use several API's available for that services such as GraceNote, Discogs or Amazon. In most cases applications download album art and info form these services and store it inside the .storage or in DCIM folder.

Comment: Where are these two directories located? On internal or external storage? And do you mean DCIM (digital camera images) or SCIM?

Comment: Yeah, I meant DCIM that was misspell. I tried 3 different applications which all of them stored in DCIM .thumbnails. I am sure it is not something you have to do it but it was that case for these applications

Comment: Never heard of .storage what is it?